# How to get the sum of a list after I grouped it

Tags: c#, linq

```
struct element
    {
        public string employeeID;
        public string objectID;
        public int quantity;
        public element(string employeeID1, string objectID1, int quantity1)
        {
            employeeID = employeeID1;
            objectID = objectID1;
            quantity = quantity1;
        }
    }
```

I have this list:

```
        list1.Add(new element("XXX1", "TV", 1));
        list1.Add(new element("XXX1", "TV", 2));
        list1.Add(new element("XXX1", "Radio", 7));
        list1.Add(new element("XXX2", "TV", 6));
        list1.Add(new element("XXX2", "Radio", 5));
        list1.Add(new element("XXX2", "Radio", 5));
```

I want a new list grouped by employeeID, then by ObjectID with their sum.
In the example above, I want to achieve this list:

```
{(XXX1", "TV", 3),("XXX1", "Radio", 7),("XXX2", "TV", 6),("XXX2", "Radio", 10)}
```

I tried this:

```
var listwithsum = list1.
            GroupBy(z => z.employeeID)
            .Select(x =>x
                    .GroupBy(result => result.objectID, result => result.quantity)
                    .Select(result => new { employeeID = x.Key, objectID = result.Key, sum = result.Sum() })
                    .ToArray()
        );
```

But, even if it works, I achieve a list wiht the elements I need, but they are in a nested list with "employeeID" as primary key.

Answer (score 4):

You only need 1 `GroupBy`

```
var listwithsum = list1
        .GroupBy(z => new { z.employeeID, z.objectID })
        .Select( x => new { x.Key.employeeID, x.Key.objectID, sum = x.Sum(y => y.quantity )});
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/OFKP61499